# My domain has got hacked/defaced by a group of hackers. What should I do next?

Tags: attacks

I don't know if this is the right forum to ask this but I have a domain hosted (shared hosting) on godaddy.com and it has been hacked/defaced by a group of Bangladeshi hackers. Note that it is just a domain hosted with GoDaddy. I haven't developed/built the site yet. This is my site -

http://anujitnene.com

What should I do next? How do I prevent such attacks? Kindly help.

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention the complete details. The domain is actually **ONLY** parked with GoDaddy. I had earlier changed its DNS servers to point to Dreamhost where I had purchased hosting. Based on the two comments received below, I reverted my DNS settings to point to GoDaddy's. It solved the problem.

Comment: I think to be more accurate, your domain was taken over. What you have is a DNS problem. Please contact GoDaddy support.

Comment: change your godaddy password and then revert the dns settings, try to keep your login details more secure in future, change all accounts where you have used the same password and change the password for the email address registered on your godaddy account

Comment: @schroeder thanks. Learned something new about Domain Hijacking.

Comment: @rdans Followed some similar steps specific to my scenario. I reverted my DNS to point to GoDaddy servers from Dreamhost's. Also, changed all the passwords. Thanks.

Comment: @schroeder can you please suggest how the hackers could have done this? What was the vulnerability they exploited?

Comment: Start by looking at dreamhosts FAQ: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Troubleshooting_Hacked_Sites 
A CGI vulnerability in software you've uploaded to your website has been exploited and used to write/execute arbitrary code on the server.
Your FTP/SSH password has been compromised.
You have world-writable directory permissions on web-accessible folders

Comment: @SteveSether but would that give them access to dns settings?

Comment: DNS has nothing to do with it.  The OP changed the hosting provider to dreamhost.

Comment: ah got it. From the original description, it sounded like there wasn't a site associated with the domain yet

Comment: @SteveSether 'A CGI vulnerability in software you've uploaded to your website'.. But I haven't uploaded anything to my site yet. I have just purchased hosting with Dreamhost, not actually 'built' the site yet. By 'software you've uploaded' does it mean the default framework which is up there with dreamhost, like PHP or Wordpress?

Comment: Some more details, I logged into my FTP account at dreamhost and can see the .php page put up by hackers and some seemingly WP folders uploaded on 17 May. How could they have done this?

Comment: Hard to say.  I was just copying the dreamhost FAQ.  But passwords and incorrectly set directory permissions are a good place to start.  If you really haven't done anything but point your DNS to dreamhost and set a hard to guess password, I'd put the blame on dreamhost and find another hosting provider.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to do...

1. Backup your important files to your local.
2. Delete everything inside.
3. Reset your hosting server.

And you're good to go. And if problems still persist, that should be GoDaddy's problems.

And, please be advised not to simply deploy any scripts that are not coming from the original author site. The scripts may have been changed to make it vulnerable. And that's why lots of webs are easily 'hacked' and gained access to it.